# Pandas - break categorical data into columns

Tags: pandas, categorical-data

I have the following table

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'foo': ['b', 'a,b', 'a,c', 'a,b,c'], 
                       'bar': ['X,Y', 'Z', 'Z,X', 'X,Y']})
```

I wish to have a table with columns 'a', 'b', 'c', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', with False/True entries.

This is NOT 1-hot encoder as multiple values are possible. How do I achiece that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need if only 2 columns double [`str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) with [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) and last cast for boolean:

```
df = df['foo'].str.get_dummies(',').join(df['bar'].str.get_dummies(',')).astype(bool)
print (df)
       a      b      c      X      Y      Z
0  False   True  False   True   True  False
1   True   True  False  False  False   True
2   True  False   True   True  False   True
3   True   True   True   True   True  False
```

If multiple columns, more general solution is `list comprehension` with [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df[x].str.get_dummies(',') for x in df.columns], axis=1).astype(bool)
```